# Why does my house get sold when I buy a garage in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When I am trying to buy a garage I lost my house when I went back. Then I tried to buy my house back and my garage got lost. I am confused I read a few articles that said I could have 6 houses/apartments/garages but I can't even get 2. Any clarification would be grateful.

Comment: This sounds like a glitch. You should contact rockstar support

Comment: Hi Noah! We need a more information to be able to answer this question. In what platform are you playing? What garage/house are you trying to buy? What are your current properties? What have you tried to do?

Comment: Higher RP level = more non-business properties. Starts at 1, and asks if you want to replace your existing property when trying to buy a new one when you only have one slot, and let's you choose a property to replace when you have multiple. Maybe this was fixed/added some point in the last 2 years.